# Error from Recordset class

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

We have some fields of type nchar to support Unicode characters.
Always encrypt is enabled for the table.
Inserting data works fine but when I try to retrieve data, the below error is thrown from Recordset Open function:

> The data types nchar(128) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'ColumnEncryptionKey1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DATABASE') and varchar(128) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'ColumnEncryptionKey1', column_encryption_key_database_name Statement(s) could not be prepared.

I am unable to understand why varchar is mentioned in the error when the table data type is nchar.
Can someone help to decipher what the error is trying to state?

SQL Server version:
SQL Server 2019 Express Edition

Table generation script:

```
USE [DATABASE]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_1](
    [secondName] [nchar](128) NULL,
    [firstName] [nchar](128) NULL,
    [Id] [nchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [height] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The query that is passed to Recordset open function is a select query with Id as search key.

```
select * from  TABLE_1 where Id=?
```

The previous error was obtained when I did remote debugging. On a similar environment when done locally, the below error is obtianed:

> The data types nchar(128) encrypted with (encryption_type =
> 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
> 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
> 'ColumnEncryptionKey1', column_encryption_key_database_name =
> 'DATABASE') and varchar(128) encrypted with (encryption_type =
> 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
> 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
> 'ColumnEncryptionKey1', column_encryption_key_database_name =
> 'DATABASE') collation Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Setting sting parameter is done in DoFieldExchange() function of Recordset class as below:

```
RFX_Text(pFX, ParameterName, *pstring, Length);
```

where pstring is of type CString*

Comment: Please post the table definition scripts. Which version and edition of SQL Server?

Comment: Added table definition script and SQL Server version information information to original query.

Comment: Please show the code where you call the Recordset Open function, including where you declare the parameters. The issue seems clear: the parameter is `varchar(128)` whereas the column is `nchar(128)`, and the server cannot convert it due to the encryption. I note that `nchar(128)` is a fixed width string, and probably the worng choice for these columns anyway.

Comment: The basic open call is done as recordset->Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, querystr, CRecordset::readOnly); . Since parameterization is required and I am using MFC/VC++, we have derived classes that support binding. So, before calling open, we prepare the SQL for the query string and set parameter values.

Comment: As I said, please show your code (in the post not in comments) and please include the code that does the parameter binding, as that is where the issue is. You are binding it as `varchar` not `nchar`

Comment: Edited query with parameter binding code.